# Make PayPal account optional at checkout

Tags: php, html, paypal

I need to receive payments with paypal and credit card, I saw a statement in developer documentation that allow me to do so:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/checkout-settings/#make-paypal-account-optional-at-c...

But I didn't see "PayPal as option" at my business settings.

How can I solve this?

I'm using html button with php POST request as Paypal Payment Standart.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if your PayPal account is Business/Premier and also make sure your PayPal email is confirmed.

Then check for the PayPal account optional setting is "on or off". It should be on.

```
Login to PayPal
Go to your Account Profile.
Select: My Selling Tools
Under: Selling Online
Locate: Website Preferences
Click on: Update
Locate: PayPal Account Optional
Click:  On
Click: Save
```

To create verified & email confirmed sandbox account, please refer the below steps:

```
1. Login to http://developer.paypal.com/ with your LIVE PayPal account
2. Click Dashboard
3. Click sandbox accounts
4. Click Create account button on the top right corner
5. Create a business account for seller and a personal account for buyer
6. Please add bank account and credit card and also populate some amount to your account
7. The email address need not be an real one.
```

Please refer the below link for your reference for creating sandbox:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Comment: http://funkyimg.com/i/2v4ah.png  
http://funkyimg.com/i/2v4ai.png  
http://funkyimg.com/i/2v4aj.png
As you can see there is no any Headers that looks like "PayPal Account Optional"

Comment: Please contact PayPal customer care support and check your country is supported with guest checkout or not. Please let me know your sandbox business account country?.

Comment: Okay. Sounxbox country is UAE.